# When using the Concatenate And Minify option, the optimized-min.css is not loaded correctly

Tags: sxa

I'm facing an issue relates to Asset Optimization in SXA. I use **Concatenate And Minify** option to optimize CSS from CSS files. However, the optimized-min.css is not loaded correctly, it still loads the old CSS even though I uploaded the latest ones, published and cleared all caches.

I found that when I switch to **Concatenate** option, the CSS works properly. But it is not my expectation because we would like to minify CSS to speed up the performance of the website. Could anyone please help me on this? Are there any issues relates to Optimization mechanism in SXA?

Currently, I'm using SXA version 1.6 and have 3 instances: 1 CM and 2 CDs.

Comment: Did you check the settings in the Sitecore/content/…/SITE_NAME/Presentation/Page Designs [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyIKn.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyIKn.png)

Comment: Yes. I checked those. The values are Default. This means they inherit global settings, e.g Concatenate And Minify option.

Comment: @Jonathan do you recall what was the solution? You answer can help me finding solution to same problem.